# Firebase Device Groups messaging works even if device registration ID does not work/ was updated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Messaging's device groups to send messages right now, and I've run into an issue where device group notification keys will still successfully send a message to devices even if their device ID has been updated.

An example would be like this:

1. Install app on Device A and get `Device_A: device_registration_ID = "25"`.
2. We create a device group with Device A `device_group_1: registration_key = "group1"`.
3. Sending a message to `device_group_A` will result in a `success`.
4. We delete and reinstall the app
5. The old `device_registation_ID = "25"` is now invalid, and a new one is created by Firebase `Device_A: device_registration_ID = "100"`
6. I create a new device group with Device A `device_group_2: registration_key = "group2"`
7. Sending a message to `device_group_2` is a `Success`
8. Sending a message to `device_registration_ID = "100"` is a `Success`
9. Sending a message to the old `device_registration_id = "25"` is a `Failure` as we expect
10. **However,** sending  a message to old `device_group_1` is **still** a `Success`

Why does the old `device_group_1` still work? The old device_registration_ID doesn't work anymore, so how does the device_group_1 even send a message to my device?

I want to maintain Device Groups such that when an app is deleted or a device_registration_ID is replaced the respective Device Group can be updated as well. I wanted to do this on the server side (Ie. check for failures when sending messages and comb through the failures to update my device_registraiton_IDs) because relying on the client code can result in some misses (Ie. if the client uninstalls the app while offline, there's no way to update the server). However, right now there's never any failures for device group messaging because even with defunct IDs they still somehow work!

Is there any other way I update my device_registration_IDs on the server side, preferably through messaging failures?

EXTRA. Creating a device group with a defunct device_registration_ID results in a `no valid registration id`